# Open a file from a new blank tab in vim

Tags: vim

If I've already opened a tab with:

```
:tabe
```

Is it possible to load the file in that tab? For example, to do something like:

`:o ~/.vimrc`

In other words, instead of doing `:tabe ~/.vimrc`, can I do that in two commands (one to open the new tab and another to open that file)?

Comment: It's `:e ~/.vimrc` - Check out this [Cheat Sheet](https://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html).

Comment: Hm, cross-posted on [vi.se]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what [Matt Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790644/matt-clark) said in the comments of your question, you can do:

```
:tabe
```

followed by

```
:e ~/.vimrc
```

vim will treat `:tabe` without arguments as opening a new tab without a file. From there you can run any vim command you want. You can basically think of it as running `vim` without arguments except now you are opening up a tab instead of the vim editor.